# Get /documentation children of context nodes with XPath

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

On [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051987/list-every-node-in-an-xml-file) about using XSLT to list every node in an XML file, Alejandro offered [this useful piece of XPath 2.0 code:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051987/list-every-node-in-an-xml-file/4053660#4053660)

EDIT: my stylesheet below now uses the modified version of the code that Alejandro kindly posted in a comment. It reports the @name attribute of elements.

I have heavily modified it to apply to a .xsd schema like the following:

Example Schema

(a simplified version of this [source](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/))

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation xml:lang="en">
 Purchase order schema for Example.com.
 Copyright 2000 Example.com. All rights reserved.
</xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>doc for comment</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="USAddress">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>doc for USAddress</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="city" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="state" type="xsd:string"/>
        <xsd:element name="zip" type="xsd:decimal"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="country" type="xsd:NMTOKEN" fixed="US"/>
</xsd:complexType>
<!-- Stock Keeping Unit, a code for identifying products -->
<xsd:simpleType name="SKU">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>doc for SKU</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="\d{3}-[A-Z]{2}"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

My XSLT Stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsl:template match="*|@*">
<xsl:value-of select="
string-join(
distinct-values(
(//*|//@*)
/string-join(
(ancestor::node()/name(),
if (self::attribute())
    then concat('@',name())
    else if (self::*[@name]) 
        then concat(name(),'[@name=&quot;',@name,'&quot;]')
        else name()),
'/')),
'&#xA;')
"/>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Results:

```
/xsd:schema
/xsd:schema/xsd:annotation
/xsd:schema/xsd:annotation/xsd:documentation
/xsd:schema/xsd:annotation/xsd:documentation/@xml:lang
/xsd:schema/xsd:element[@name="comment"]
/xsd:schema/xsd:element/@name
/xsd:schema/xsd:element/@type
/xsd:schema/xsd:element/xsd:annotation
/xsd:schema/xsd:element/xsd:annotation/xsd:documentation
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType[@name="USAddress"]
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/@name
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:annotation
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:annotation/xsd:documentation
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name="name"]
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element/@name
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element/@type
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name="street"]
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name="city"]
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name="state"]
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element[@name="zip"]
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:attribute[@name="country"]
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:attribute/@name
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:attribute/@type
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:attribute/@fixed
/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType[@name="SKU"]
/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType/@name
/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType/xsd:annotation
/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType/xsd:annotation/xsd:documentation
/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType/xsd:restriction
/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType/xsd:restriction/@base
/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType/xsd:restriction/xsd:pattern
/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType/xsd:restriction/xsd:pattern/@value
```

This output is fine, for the purposes of this question.

Now, rather than asking "what's wrong with my fugly code?" I'll just ask the best way to proceed from a base state that actually works.

I need to add a clause that, for every line with a `/xsd:documentation` grandchild, appends the text from `<xsd:documentation>foo</xsd:documentation>`. So this line:

```
/xsd:schema/xsd:element[@name="comment"]
```

becomes:

```
/xsd:schema/xsd:element[@name="comment"] | doc for comment
```

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and simple solution.

Comment: In addition to @Dimitre good answer, I'm going to resume to you the expression semantic: outermost `string-join()` it's just a prettifier; `distinct-values()` is for stripping duplicated path; `(//*|//@*)` is the generator, it means *"any element and attribute from the whole document"*; the innermost `string-join()` is in fact a modified path generator from the [specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-string-join), it uses `node()` to select the root (empty QName); the `if` expression is just for adding `@` character to attribute's path (maybe I should use `instance of`)

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks for your explanation. I face two challenges here: the first is returning a more useful schema instance identifier than `xsd:element` or `xsd:complexType.` Instead of `/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element` I want `/xsd:schema/USAddress/xsd:sequence/street,` for example. I think I can kludge my way through that using your code. Including the name-conversion code in this question was unwise, though.      This question is about the second challenge, which is to grab the /documentation grandchild for any element that has one and concat() it to the line.

Comment: For that you need to modify the `if` expression outputing the name to: `if (self::attribute()) then concat('@',name()) else if (self::*[@name]) then concat(name(),'[@name="',@name,'"]') else name()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The solution is simple**:

.1. Define the `xsd` namespace in your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
>
```

.2. Change:

```
.//documentation
```

to

```
.//xsd:documentation
```

**BTW, this is wrong**:

```
//xsd|//@*
```

There is no element named `xsd` in the document. Probably you want:

```
//xsd:*|//@*
```

Also, there is no need to use `local-name()` on attributes, just `name()` is OK.

**Second observation:**

There is nothing wrong with Alejandro's solution. Applied to the provided XML document it produces the following correct output:

```
/xsd:schema
/xsd:schema/xsd:annotation
/xsd:schema/xsd:annotation/xsd:documentation
/xsd:schema/xsd:annotation/xsd:documentation/@xml:lang
/xsd:schema/xsd:element
/xsd:schema/xsd:element/@name
/xsd:schema/xsd:element/@type
/xsd:schema/xsd:element/xsd:annotation
/xsd:schema/xsd:element/xsd:annotation/xsd:documentation
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/@name
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element/@name
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:sequence/xsd:element/@type
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:attribute
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:attribute/@name
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:attribute/@type
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:attribute/@fixed
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:annotation
/xsd:schema/xsd:complexType/xsd:annotation/xsd:documentation
/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType
/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType/@name
/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType/xsd:restriction
/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType/xsd:restriction/@base
/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType/xsd:restriction/xsd:pattern
/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType/xsd:restriction/xsd:pattern/@value
/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType/xsd:annotation
/xsd:schema/xsd:simpleType/xsd:annotation/xsd:documentation
```

Comment: Dimitre, thanks for responding. This has confused me. Should I define the namespace in the stylesheet with `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` , just like in the .xsd file? Or should the xsd namespace point to the schema file itself? Neither approach seems to be working so far.

Comment: +1 also for catching the select clause. I've changed it to `(//schema|//@*)` since `//xsd:*` returns too many items, and I'm using .//xsd:documentation but still no results are coming through.

Comment: @MW-Frost: Just do exactly as I recommend -- rdited the answer so now the code is formatted and readable.

Comment: @Dimitre: I'm going to tentatively check this as the answer while trying to make it work in another parser. Thanks!

Comment: @MW-Frost: Why didn't you use @Alejandro's solution? See my edited answer.

Comment: @Dimitre: In my actual application I need to describe the schema objects by `@name` rather than by `name()`. A list that reports xsd:element, xsd:complexType, etc. doesn't suit my needs. So I have tweaked it to report the attributes and their values, and now I'm trying to get `/annotation/documentation` as well.

Comment: @Dimitre: Aside from the xml/xsd differences that my previous comment describes, is is possible to modify Alejandro's code so that the /xsd:annotation/xsd:documentation objects are written out when they exist?

Comment: @MW-Frost: There are *many* issues with your expression. It would be best (and I can help) if you provide a very small example and the exact wanted result, and explain what you really want. Otherwise, withowt knowing what you really want to achieve, nobody will be able to help and you remain tangled to something that you do not fully understand.

Comment: @Dimitre: It's not pretty. I'm not proud.

Comment: @Dimitre: I'll develop a set of stripped-down examples and post clarified versions tomorrow.

Comment: @Dimitre: +1 Good answer and analisys.

Comment: @MW Frost: I think you need to post your desired output in order to help you.

Comment: I can't get XSLPalette to work on my home computer, so unfortunately I can't revise and simplify my post tonight. Thank you both for your help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

`.//xsd:documentation` was trying to get all the documentation children in the schema. I fixed the problem by using `./xsd:documentation` instead.

The new clause that reports documentation for any element after the test to see if it's an attribute:

```
concat(
if (self::*[@name]) 
then @name
else name()
, ./xsd:documentation)
```

Thanks for everyone's help.